# Update partial view from drop down list selection using MVC 5 EF 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on my third year project and I'm struggling with this one section so badly, I have looked around and found some answers but I really done know how to implement in my code because it always just doesn't work. So I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

What i would like is for the partial view to change when the drop down selected item has changed.

This is what was generated in the view for this section.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TypeID, "TypeID", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("TypeID", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TypeID)
    </div>
</div>
```

Most solutions I have seen use a @html.dropdownlistfor().

Any help would be appreciated even if you could just point me to the right place.

[image]

The drop down list is filled from the database relationships.

I have got this to work if i use labels in an "a" tag with an href but they are hard coded onto the page. I want to use the drop down list so that if i update the database it will have the updated list instead of me going to change it in the code, its also more user friendly in my eyes.

Thanx in advance

Comment: You need to handle the `.change()` event of the dropdown in javascript/jquery and use ajax to call a server method and update the DOM, or redirect to a new view. But there is no reason to hard code your linsk - you can just use a loop based on the collection from your database

Comment: @Stephen Muecke Thank you, would i put the ajax inside my jquery function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could retrieve the data from the server and construct/change the DOM via JQuery, or you could use a partial view that is appropriate for each question type, attaching an event handler to the `change` event of the drop-down via JQuery.

One approach, loading partial views:

yourNamespace.yourScript.js file (include the file in your main view via the `<script>` tag with the `src` attribute):

```
    (function ($) {     
        if (!window.yourNamespace) {
            window.yourNamespace = {};
        }
        if (!window.yourNamespace.yourPageScript) {
            window.yourNamespace.yourPageScript = function () {
                var populateView = function (dropDown) {
                    if (dropDown && dropDown.length) {
                        var value = dropdown.val();
                        $.ajax({
                            method: "GET",
                            cache: false,
                            url: "some.url/PopulateType",
                            dataType: "HTML"
                            data: { selectedValue: value }
                        })
                        .done(function (response) { // jQuery 1.8 deprecates success() callback
                            var div = $('#partialViewDiv');
                            div.html('');
                            div.html(response);
                        });
                    }
                };

                return {
                    populateView: populateView
                };
            };
        }
    }(jQuery));
```

Your main view could have something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // put the script section somewhere appropriate in the page
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var dropDown = $('#TypeId'); // assuming the ID of this element is 'TypeId'
        dropDown.change(function () {
            yourNamespace.yourPageScript.populateView(dropDown);
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="partialViewDiv">
@Html.RenderPartial("path to initial partial view", model);
</div>
```

partial view example (adjust to be proper for any particular dropdown selection):

```
@model namespaceName.QuestionTypeModel

<div class="form-group>
    @* put controls appropriate to the particular partial views here, such as radio buttons for the multiple choice question type, etc. *@
<div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TypeID, "TypeID", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("TypeID", Model.QuestionTypeValues)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TypeID)
   </div>
</div>
```

Part of the controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MainViewModel();
        // populate the model with data here for the initial display, including the initial drop-down values, 
        // presumably the same way you do now
        // into model.QuestionTypeValues

        return View(model); // the main view
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult PopulateType(int selectedValue) // could use an enum for the selectable values
    {
        var model = new QuestionViewModel();

        string partialViewName = null;
        // populate with data appropriate to the partial views
        switch (selectedValue)
        {
            case 0:
                partialViewName = "partial view name for item 0";
                // populate "model" with the appropriate data
                break;
            case 1:
                partialViewName = "partial view name for item 1";
                 // populate "model" with the appropriate data
                break;
            // and so on...
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("unknown selected value", "selectedValue");
                break;
        }

        return PartialView(partialViewName, model);
    }
```

The approach to use jQuery to build the DOM elements instead of using partial views is left as an exercise.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the detailed answer, I will mark it as correct cause it looks like you know what you're doing and I assume my implementation of it was wrong, if you have time and would like to help further, it would be appreciated, i will play around with it further and try to get it right.

The main problem is that im brand new to jquery, ajax and mvc all together.

Comment: I can help further, just try to understand what I've got there and feel free to ask any questions about it that you have.

Comment: Currently just busy with my last two exams, I will ask away when I'm done :)